# TypeError: object is not callable | While creating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, spyder

While trying to create a dictionary using : dict(name = "John", age = 36, country = "Norway") (just an example but very similar). Editor keeps returning the Error message: object is not callable !
The syntax as I checked repeatedly is correct, I suspect that this is related maybe to my compiler   (I'm using Spyder/Anaconda)!!
Does anyone know how to overcome this ?

I tried to create a dictionary using dict()

Comment: You probably used `dict` as a variable name earlier in the program.

Comment: please, if you are recieving an error, don't put your own abridged version of the error message, include the *full error message with the stack trace*. copy-and-paste it.

Comment: @Barmar you're right I did it a while ago thanks!